# ¿Como armo una calculadora con el ciclo Do While?

Tags: javascript

La pregunta es simple, todavia no logro decifrarlo.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Es valido tener tantos Do While en una sola operación?

El codigo es el siguiente:

```html
 
     <div>
     <input type="number" id = a />
        <input type="number" id = b />

        <input type="button" onclick="suma(document.getElementById('a').value,document.getElementById('b').value);" value="Sumar"/>

        <input type="button" onclick="resta(document.getElementById('a').value,document.getElementById('b').value);" value="Restar"/>

        <input type="button" onclick="multiplicar(document.getElementById('a').value,document.getElementById('b').value);" value="Multiplicacion"/>

        <input type="button" onclick="dividir(document.getElementById('a').value,document.getElementById('b').value);" value="Division"/>
    </div>
```

En el HTML tengo cuatro inputs onclick de manera que por cada numero insertado, realize la operacion matematica. Aca esta el JS donde describo cada Do While.

Agrego este comentario de relleno para que pueda insertar el codigo html. Saludos

```js
do {
  suma = Number(a) + Number(b)
  break;
}

while (a, b)

alert (suma);

do {
  resta = Number(a) - Number(b)
  break;
}

while (a, b)

alert (resta);

do {
  multiplicar = Number(a) * Number(b)
  break;
}

while (a, b)

alert (multiplicar);

do {
  dividir = Number(a) / Number(b)
  break;
}

while (a, b)

alert (dividir);
```

Comment: Entiendo que desea hacer una calculadora pero El uso del do {} while() en tu codigo no le veo mucho sentido, si puedes explicarte mejor la razon que necesitas usar ese ciclo en particular e incluye tambien el codigo  HTML

Comment: @AlexanderRodriguez Así es el ejercicio que me mandaron a hacer. De manera que si no tuviese condiciones lo hubiese realizado con functiones. Quise agregar el código HTML pero no me deja por qué según hay mucho código y muy poco detalle

Comment: bueno, de ser asi la unica explicacion que veo es que se este evaluando la entrada de datos y al colocar un valor especificio, Se sale del ciclo. Dame un minuto para poder ayudarte

Comment: El código no está completo porque no has declarado las variables a y b ni cuando debe ejecutarse las operaciones.

Comment: Podrias tratar de explicar que hiciste en tu codigo, y que tratabas de hacer? es confuso que intentaste hacer con tantos de while, o que fue lo que te pidieron que hicieras.

Comment: Agradezco mucho la ayuda de Alex, el cual me dio una respuesta desde otro punto de vista. Las variables "A" y "B" estaban declaradas ya en el html, lo cual ahora si se visualizan.

Comment: Lo que trate de hacer fue una calculadora usando solamente el ciclo Do While (usando solamente suma, resta, multiplicacion y division). Y tener dos inputs en html para insertar los caracteres numericos. Una vez hecho eso, el usuario elegira que operacion matematica usara entre esos dos caracteres.

Comment: Y el do while que es lo que haria en este caso? porque no tiene mucho sentido segun eso que explicas

Comment: Es por eso que pregunto, por que ademas de no saber si es correcto utilizar tantos Do While, lo que harian (en mi codigo ejemplar) es utilizarlo como un function. La pregunta del posteo es esta: ¿Como armo una calculadora con el ciclo Do While?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NUEVA solución (SIN COMANDO EVAL)**  aqui se aplica en dos oportunidades el codigo  `do {} while ()` para la calculadora. En la primera parte se recibe una entrada por consola los datos y los evalue para mostrar el resultado, entonces la unica forma de salir del ciclo y hacer otra cosas seria tipeando "exit" en la entrada, lo cual terminaria el ciclo do while.

Actualizando la respuesta la segunda parte de usar el codigo `do {} while()` es ahora donde se evalua la expresion aritmetica **sin usar eval()** tambien esta funcion cumple con el `do {} while ()` al evaluar la cadena para sacar los operadores, numeradores y denominadores, con cada operacion  mientras va acomulando el valor anterior y se procede a ejecutar el siguiente calculo hasta concluir todas las operaciones de la cadena y se termina el ciclo, el nuevo codigo emplea expresiones regulares por lo que se coloca el link para ampliar informacion.

link de expresiones regulares:

https://codeburst.io/an-introduction-to-regular-expressions-regex-in-javascript-1d3559e7ac9a

**Adjunto nuevo codigo** documentado de calculadora con `do {} while()` 
en el area de ejecucion:

```js
        // funcion de calculadora con do {} while()
         function calculadora() { 
            var correr = true; // var de salida
            // para historial de calculos      
            do {
                var entrada = prompt("Calculadora lineal (coloque su operacion / para salir tipee: exit)");
                if (entrada=='exit') {
                    correr=false;
                    alert('Adios..')
                } else {
                    calculo = calculoSinEval(entrada); // evaluacion de expresion 
                    salida = entrada + ' = ' + calculo;
                    alert('Resultado de : ' + salida);
                        // crear nueva li para historico de calculo
                        var node = document.createElement("LI");
                        var textnode = document.createTextNode(salida);
                        node.appendChild(textnode);
                        document.getElementById("historico").appendChild(node);
                }
            } while (correr);
         };



        // funcion para calcular sin usar eval()
        function calculoSinEval(entrada) {
        
                // declaracion de variables usadas
                var valorA=0;
                var valorB=0;
                var calculo =0;
                var operador='';
                var ciclo =true;
                var paso=0;
                var cadena =entrada; // entrada de operacion de calculo
                var expNum = /[\d|.|]+/; // exp para numeros int / flotante
                var expOper = /[-|\|+|-|*|//]/; // exp para operador + - * /

                do {
                    paso++;

                    // pone ultimo valor calculado para volver a operar 
                    if (paso>1) {
                        cadena = calculo.toString().concat(cadena);
                    } 

                    // 1) PARA el primer valor
                    valorA= cadena.match(expNum); // tomar numero encontrado por exp de numero
                    if (valorA==null) { break;  }
                    cadena= cadena.replace(valorA, ""); // quitar numero encontrado
                    ciclo = (valorA.length-length==0)? false : true;  // si no se consigue el primer numero se sale
             
                    // 2) PARA el segundo valor
                    valorB= cadena.match(expNum); // tomar numero encontrado por exp de numero
                    cadena= cadena.replace(valorB, ""); // quitar numero encontrado

                    // 3) Para el operador
                    operador= cadena.match(expOper); // tomar numero encontrado por exp de numero
                    cadena= cadena.replace(operador, ""); // quitar numero encontrado
                        // si no se consigue operador se sale del ciclo.
                        if (operador==null) {  break; } 
                           
                    operador=operador.toString(); // convierte operador en string para el switch
                    // calculo de operacion artimeticas
                    switch (operador) {
                        case '+':
                            calculo = parseFloat(valorA) + parseFloat(valorB);
                        break;
                        case '-':
                            calculo = parseFloat(valorA) - parseFloat(valorB);
                        break;
                        case '*':
                            calculo = parseFloat(valorA) * parseFloat(valorB);
                        break;
                        case '/':
                            calculo = parseFloat(valorA) / parseFloat(valorB);
                        break;
                        default:
                            calculo=null;
                            ciclo = false; // si falla el calculo se sale;
                        break;
                    }
              
                // si no hay mas contenido se sale del ciclo
                if (cadena.length<=1) {
                    ciclo = false;
                }
                    
                } while (ciclo);

                 return calculo; // salida de calculo

        }  // fin de funcion calculoSinEval()
```

```html
        <h2>Calculadora lineal</h2>
        <p> Colocque su calculo ej: 5 + 5</p>
        <p> para Salir tipee: exit</p>
        <input type="button" value="pulse iniciar" onclick="calculadora()">
        <ul id="historico">
        </ul>
```

Basandome en esta idea hice el siguiente codigo de calculadora:

```
<script>
     // funcion de calculadora con do {} while()
     function calculadora() { 
        var correr = true; // var de salida
        // para historial de calculos      
        do {
            var entrada = prompt("Calculadora lineal (coloque su operacion / para salir tipee: exit)");
            if (entrada=='exit') {
                correr=false;
                alert('Adios..')
            } else {
                calculo = eval(entrada); // evaluacion de expresion 
                salida = entrada + ' = ' + calculo;
                alert('Resultado de : ' + salida);
                    // crear nueva li para historico de calculo
                    var node = document.createElement("LI");
                    var textnode = document.createTextNode(salida);
                    node.appendChild(textnode);
                    document.getElementById("historico").appendChild(node);
            }
        } while (correr);
     };
</script>
```

**Explicacion:**

1) Hice una funcion que tiene un ciclo do {} while() y se llama con el boton "pulsar iniciar".

2) se declara y asigna la variable **correr** como **true** para el ciclo `do while()` ella al ponerla como **false** terminara el ciclo.

3) La variable entrada recibe los datos del `prompt()` para su calculo y evaluacion.

4) si **(entrada = "exit")** entonces se termina el ciclo al asignar a la variable `correr = false`.

5) La variable **calculo** ejecuta el comando `eval()` que evalua una expresion dentro de la variable e**ntrada**.

6) La variable salida arma la operacion  y resultado

7) Con el comando alert() mostramos la variable salida

**HiSTORICO DE OPERACIONES**

8) Se crea un nodo para agregar una etiqueta LI en UL para el historial

9) Creamos un valor al node con la variable **salida**

10) Asignamos el valor del node con la etiqueta creada LI

11) Agregamos la etiqueta creada `LI` al `UL` con `id="historico"`, el cual sera mostrado una vez finalizado el ciclo **do while**

**Ejecucion del codigo:**

```js
         // funcion de calculadora con do {} while()
         function calculadora() { 
            var correr = true; // var de salida
            // para historial de calculos      
            do {
                var entrada = prompt("Calculadora lineal (coloque su operacion / para salir tipee: exit)");
                if (entrada=='exit') {
                    correr=false;
                    alert('Adios..')
                } else {
                    calculo = eval(entrada); // evaluacion de expresion 
                    salida = entrada + ' = ' + calculo;
                    alert('Resultado de : ' + salida);
                        // crear nueva li para historico de calculo
                        var node = document.createElement("LI");
                        var textnode = document.createTextNode(salida);
                        node.appendChild(textnode);
                        document.getElementById("historico").appendChild(node);
                }
            } while (correr);
         };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <h2>Calculadora lineal</h2>
    <p> Colocque su calculo ej: 5 + 5</p>
    <p> para Salir tipee: exit</p>
    <input type="button" value="pulse iniciar" onclick="calculadora()">
    <ul id="historico">
    </ul>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero que sea de ayuda...

Comment: Aunque es una respuesta muy interesante, no le explica a OP su problema, que es el uso incorrecto del do..while. Y aparte, hace un uso abusivo de eval, que en general no seria recomendable en una clase delante de un profesor. No digo que la respuesta sea mala, pero no contesta la pregunta.

Comment: Yo pregunte ante de exponer una respuesta cual es la razon por la cual le estan pidiendo el uso del ciclo do while en una calculadora, a mi juicio de razon debe ser que ejecuta la entrada de datos de manera infinita hasta que tipee una salida. En cuanto al comando eval() tienes toda la razon, no se aprende mucho, pero es un recurso de facil empleo para evaluar una expresion sin agregar codigo extra.